# Spark Alternative to SubQuery using same table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This post is about how spark is inefficient joining a table with a subquery using the same table. Using Spark 2.2 and Scala.

I have a table (fieldcnts) with the following schema:

```
|key |name |value |cnt |keycnt |minkeycnt|type |
|A   |f1   |123   |3   |100    |30       |-1   |
|A   |f1   |234   |5   |100    |30       |-1   |
|A   |f2   |345   |50  |225    |75       |-1   |
|B   |f1   |456   |40  |100    |30       |-1   |
...
```

This table is derived from a cached table with the following query (Q1):

```
SELECT key, 'f1' AS name, f1 AS value, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       first(keycnt) AS keycnt, first(keymincnt) AS keymincnt
FROM table1
GROUP BY key, f1
UNION ALL
SELECT key, 'f2' AS name, f2 AS value, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       first(keycnt) AS keycnt, first(keymincnt) AS keymincnt
FROM table1
GROUP BY key, f2
UNION ALL
...
(simiarly for f3, f4 and f5)
```

The schema of table1 is:

```
|key|f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|keycnt|keymincnt|
```

So the fieldcnts table at this stage has the counts of each (key,f*)-tuple. I currently have keycnt and keymincnt (a percentage of keycnt) stored redundantly in each row to avoid an extra join and calculation, though this may change later if I get better performance w/ a join and smaller dataset.

The type field is by default -1. I need to subsequently set this to one of 4 values depending on some conditions. I doing this with the following query (Q2):

```
SELECT R.key, R.name, R.value, R.cnt
    CASE 
        WHEN ${cond1} THEN -2
        WHEN ${cond2} THEN -3
        WHEN ${cond3} THEN -4
        ELSE -1
    END AS type
FROM fieldcnts R
JOIN (SELECT key, name, COUNT(*) AS numrecs, SUM(CASE WHEN cnt >= keymincnt THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS fieldsum
      FROM fieldcnts
      GROUP BY key, name) AS S
ON R.key = S.key AND R.name = S.name
```

Where each ${condn} is a condition involving cnt, keymincnt, keycnt, fieldsum and numrecs (like (A < B) AND ((C - D) > B) (probably pretty proprietary, just in case!)

So this works, but while tuning I noticed that because of the subquery in Q2 using the same table as the outer query, it forces the subquery to read off of disk (parquet scan). This is trouble because this is happening for every query within the Q1 UNION ALL query!

I noticed this first when computing table1. A set of parquet files are read in, it selects a subset of fields and then I filter out all rows where keycnt < x:

```
SELECT R.key, R.f1, R.f2, R.f3, R.f4, R.f5, S.cnt AS keycnt, 0.33*S.cnt AS keymincnt
FROM tbl R
JOIN (SELECT key, COUNT(*) AS keycnt
      FROM tbl T
      GROUP BY key
      HAVING keycnt >= ${minCnt}) AS S
ON R.key = S.key
```

(In reality tbl was used well prior to this so I'm receiving it cached at this point). Looking at the DAG I could clearly see the outer table being read from cache, while the inner table is read from disk! I actually solved this using Windowing:

```
val dfSQL = spark.sql("SELECT key, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 FROM tbl")
    .withColumn("keycnt", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"key")))
    .withColumn("keymincnt", $"key"*0.33)
    .filter($"keycnt" >= minCnt)
```

Much better. No SortMergeJoin or disk read in this case.

Now back to Q2: this is a similar case to the table1 query but much more complex. I could not come up with a scheme using Windowing yet (still kind of novice with spark). Is there a way to use Windowing here? Alternatively is there a way to prevent spark from reading from disk for a subquery using the same table?

Thanks!

**Update**
Coming back around to this. My colleague came across a different solution: using mapPartitions, which fit my problem much better.

I kept this query which distributes to partitions by key, exactly what I want:

```
SELECT R.key, R.f1, R.f2, R.f3, R.f4, R.f5, S.cnt AS keycnt, 0.33*S.cnt AS keymincnt
FROM tbl R
JOIN (SELECT key, COUNT(*) AS keycnt
    FROM tbl T
    GROUP BY key
    HAVING keycnt >= ${minCnt}) AS S
ON R.key = S.key
```

Then I wrote the rest of the algorithm in mapPartitions scala function. Much cleaner, much faster.

Comment: sort merge is not by definition bad

Comment: This is true, but rereading the data off of disk 5x multiple is (and then each performing the same table1 transformation). Im sure there must be a way to accomplish the same transformation while using strictly the cached table

Comment: Agree, but two seperate issues.